# Dynamic Port Forwarding Automation and Which Ports?

Tags: networking, ssh, proxy, port-forwarding, ssh-tunnel

I've successfully enabled dynamic port forwarding in my web browser.  Now I'd like to go a few steps further if that's at all possible.

1) There is software that monitors network traffic on a computer:  Firewalls (think Zone Alarm, Total Defense Security etc).  So why can't a software service run on my computer and monitor specific ports without having to enable SOCKS in individual apps?  I travel with my laptop a few times a year and it'd be easy to forget to enable or disable SOCKS in one or more app.

2) How would I go about figuring out what ports an app uses so that I can make sure to set up the required port forwarding.  For example, I use Quicken 2013 and it syncs' to the Quicken cloud service but I have no idea what port(s) it uses.  I also don't seen anything way in it to use SOCKS.

3) When my laptop detects that I'm connecting to a new network, it asks me if it's a Home, Work or Public network.  What I'd LOVE to do is make it so that if I'm connected to anything not designated as HOME, then automatically enable the DynPort Forwarding.

Comment: You may want to better describe what you are trying to do.  I wonder if "Dynamic Port Forwarding" is actually an appropriate solution, or if you should be looking at a VPN and /or  firewall rules.

Comment: I ended up setting up OpenVPN and it works quite well.   Thanks for the suggestion.